# How to str_replace tick charset

Tags: php, tcpdf

I use tcpdf to print pdf, but when I print a tick sign &#10004, it gives me question mark sign,

Have googling on one hours, but still no success.

This is the html that I will be print on pdf :

```
$html2= '<tr class="odd" role="row">
   <td tabindex="0">1</td><td>0.35 MM X 101 MM</td>
   <td>02BIXTL16040851/62</td>
   <td>AS70</td>
   <td>G550</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>4692</td>
   <td>4740</td>
   <td>1355</td>
   <td>JST-10339</td>
   <td>A10909</td>
   <td><h3>✔</h3></td>
   <td><h3>✔</h3></td>
   <td><h3>✔</h3></td>
   <td ></td>
   <td ></td>
   <td ></td>
</tr>';
```

On tcpdf :

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0.2">
<tr style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:#0000FF;">
    <td width="30" align="center"><b> No.  </b></td>
    <td width="80" align="center"><b> Size </b></td>
    <td width="85" align="center"><b> Code Of Coil </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Coating </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Spec </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Number Of Palet </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Weigth (Net) </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Weigth (Gross) </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Length </b></td>
    <td width="45" align="center"><b> Contract No </b></td>
    <td width="45" align="center"><b> Location </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Dent In </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Dent Out </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Dent End </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Wet </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> No Damage </b></td>
    <td width="35" align="center"><b> Others </b></td>


</tr>
EOD;

        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 6);
        $tbl .= utf8_decode($html2)  ;
        $tbl .= "</table>";
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, 5, 90, $tbl, 0, 0, false, true, '', true);
```

I try to change utf-8 to  ISO-8859-1, but still not work. Any help it so appreciated

Comment: Isn't it the font that just might not contain the character? Have you tried a different font?

Comment: Thanks, dejavusans is working.

Comment: I put it in as an answer, as I suppose others might face the same question (mark) ...

Comment: As a reference for the future, I think it would be *extremely* unlikely such issues are fixed by moving *away* from `UTF-8` to less universal character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different font. It might just be the font you are using does not have that character.